# im experiencing this error when running a program "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Tags: python, math, calculator

i am attempting to build a composite function calculator, but I'm running into some issues.

```
import math

xval = input(int("what is the value of X?"))

fval = input(str("what is the value of f?"))

gval = input(str("what is the value of f?"))
```

this is the bit of code that isn't working. For the "xval" variable  i keep on getting the error message

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'what is the value
>   of X?'

I've looked around online, but I can't find any issues with my code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first execute `input` and then `int` to cast the result into an integer number.

Otherwise you are trying to convert a text into an integer

```
xval = int(input("what is the value of X?"))
```

In the other lines, the `str` is redundant, but is it really what you want? I mean to me it looks like `fval` and `gval` should also be numbers.

Ah, and the text for gval should be "what is the value of **g**"

Also take in account that `int` will convert your inputs to integers, if you need decimal numbers consider using `float()`

**Explanation:**

Your original line `input(int("what is the value of X?"))` basically does the following steps:

1. Creates the string "what is the value of X?"
2. Tries to convert this string to an integer number (and fails)
3. Supposing point 2 doesn't fail (which does), then it will execute `input` giving an integer as text (and failing again) and storing your input as a string. As a result your variable `xval` would be a string (which is not what you want)

Instead, what you want is to first execute `input` and convert the value that you type into an integer, so you have to execute:

```
xval = int(input("what is the value of X?"))
```

Note that if you input a string, then the cast into `int()` will fail, you might want to use `try` and catch a possible exeption.

Comment: I'm quite new to programming, so could you please explain what you mean by that? edit: sorry, i understand now. i put int in the wrong place. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3.x, Python 3.x doesn't evaluate and convert the data type, you have to explicitly convert to int

```
x = int(input("what is the value of X?"))
```

If you are using Python2.x, you need to do like this:

```
x = input("what is the value of X?")
```

You can then check the type of x using type(x), you will get `<type 'int'>`